# Add jquery mobile only for mobile and tablet

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, tablet

I want to have jQuery Mobile only if user is on a mobile or a tablet.

I was thinking to use [Simple-RESS](https://github.com/jiolasa/Simple-RESS). This script allow me to access device screen.

The problem is that tablet screen resolutions are approaching desktop resolutions.

How can I correctly target mobile and tablet ? only with user agent ?

Answer (score 0):

I think user agent is the best bet. You can however use viewport metadata tags and [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) in your header to adapt your site to different screen sizes using different stylesheets.